# Is there a way to spellcheck JSON object keys against existing Java object values using Jackson (or a similar library)?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm deserializing a JSON object using Jackson, and so far the process has allowed me to successfully convert a JSON object to a Java object.

However, I am imagining a scenario where a user sends JSON in the body of their request and one or many of the keys is misspelled. For example, what if Jackson is expecting `{"jurisdiction": "Maine"}` but the user misspells the key and sends `{"jrdiction": "Maine"}`.

Is there any way to essentially use Jackson to check the @JsonProperty of a Java value and compare it to the JSON in the request, and then return something like: `Property "jrdiction" doesn't exist. Did you mean "jurisdiction"?`

I am aware that Jackson will throw an `UnrecognizedPropertyException` when there are properties that don't exist in the Java class. However, what if I want to ignore unknown properties (allow users to send anything in the JSON object) but also have a spellcheck that informs them that a property might be misspelled?

Comment: You could validate the JSON against a JSON schema, [see this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-json-schema-in-java). Or do you mean to forgo a definition and only check against the fields of the object you are deserializing to?

Comment: @xtratic Thanks for the link. Ideally I want to forgo a definition and only check against the fields of the object that I am deserializing to.  I realize the constraints of my problem are fairly narrow. Basically I want to allow the user to send any arbitrary JSON object, but catch potential spelling mistakes for existing fields on an object

Comment: I've some ideas. Gimme a bit.

Comment: take your time. I've got all day ;)

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge i don't think Jackson have such kind of support, but one way to achieve this can be achieved by adding below code into your POJO class.

```
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

This setter and getter will add all the unmatched or unknown keys/properties which is not available in your POJO into the map.

Then you can check the size of the map and if its non-zero than you can look for the most relevant keys for that unknown key(s). There might be chances if the key can have more than matches. Now it's up to your handling if how you want to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is multi-part:

- Firstly, you need to know all the json keys that did not match a field in the json object.
- Secondly, you need to know the objects json fields available so that you can find the closest match to a misspelled json key.
- Lastly, you need a way to actually calculate the closest matches between an unmatched json key and the available json fields.

You can get all the JSON data keys that didn't match any JSON object fields using `@JsonAnySetter` as suggested by [Shivang Agarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53949771/2442526).

```
public static class MyParent {
    @JsonProperty("a") protected String jsonA;
    @JsonProperty("b") protected String jsonB;
    // ignored by getJsonPropertyNames()
    protected String internal1;
    @JsonIgnore private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    @JsonAnyGetter public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }
    @JsonAnySetter public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
}
public static class MyChild extends MyParent {
    @JsonProperty("jurisdiction") protected String jurisdiction;
    // ignored by getJsonPropertyNames()
    protected String internal2;
}
```

---

You can get all the avail able JSON fields (annotated with `@JsonProperty`) from the object using the below methods:

```
private static Collection<String> getJsonPropertyNames(Object o) {
    // might need checking if fields collide
    // Eg:
    //   @JSONProperty String field1;
    //   @JSONProperty("field1") String fieldOne;
    // maybe should be a Set?
    List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    forAllFields(o, (f) -> {
        JsonProperty jprop = f.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class);
        if (jprop != null) {
            String fieldName = jprop.value();
            if (fieldName == null) {
                fieldName = f.getName();
            }
            fields.add(fieldName);
        }
    });
    return fields;
}

/** For all fields of the given object, including its parent fields */
private static void forAllFields(Object o, Consumer<Field> consumer) {
    Class<?> klass = o.getClass();
    while (klass != null) {
        for (Field f : klass.getDeclaredFields())
            consumer.accept(f);
        klass = klass.getSuperclass();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    for (String s : getJsonPropertyNames(new MyChild()))
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

---

You can find the most similar strings using the below methods:

*I still want to test my `stringEditDistance` method some more but it might work well enough for now. I might work on it some more later.*

```
/** finds the nearest matching string from the options
  * using the basic string edit distance where all operations cost 1 */
private static String findNearestMatch(String input, Iterable<String> options) {
    String closestString = null;
    int minDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (String option : options) { 
        int distance = stringEditDistance(input, option, 1, 1, (a, b) -> 1);
        if (distance < minDistance) {
            minDistance = distance;
            closestString = option;
        }
    }
    return closestString;
}

/**
 * NOTE: needs some editing and more testing.
 *
 * Returns the minimum cost to edit the input string into the target string using the given costs for
 * operations.
 * 
 * @param insertCost
 *            the cost to insert a character into the input to bring it closer to the target
 * @param deleteCost
 *            the cost to delete a character from the input to bring it closer to the target
 * @param replaceCostCalculator
 *            a function to calculate the cost to replace a character in the input to bring it close
 *            to the target
 */
public static int stringEditDistance(String input, String target, int insertCost, int deleteCost,
        BiFunction<Character, Character, Integer> replaceCalculator) {
    int[][] dp = new int[input.length() + 1][target.length() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= input.length(); i++)
        dp[i][0] = i;
    for (int j = 0; j <= target.length(); j++)
        dp[0][j] = j;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char cInput = input.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < target.length(); j++) {
            char cTarget = target.charAt(j);
            if (cInput == cTarget) {
                dp[i + 1][j + 1] = dp[i][j];
            } else {
                int replace = dp[i][j] + replaceCalculator.apply(cInput, cTarget);
                int insert = dp[i][j + 1] + insertCost;
                int delete = dp[i + 1][j] + deleteCost;
                int min = Math.min(replace, Math.min(insert, delete));
                dp[i + 1][j + 1] = min;
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[input.length()][target.length()];
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // serialize a json object
    // edit this json to test with other bad input keys
    final String json = "{ \"a\" : \"1\", \"b\" : \"2\", \"jrdiction\" : \"3\" }";
    MyChild child = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(MyChild.class).readValue(json);

    // List<String> jsonProps = getJsonPropertyNames(child);
    // create the list of jsonProps for yourself so you can edit and test easily
    List<String> jsonProps = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "jurisdiction");
    for (Entry<String, Object> e : child.getAdditionalProperties().entrySet()) {
        String nearest = findNearestMatch(e.getKey(), jsonProps);
        System.out.println(e.getKey() + " is closest to " + nearest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad but I will try to give you some starting points for further research by a simple example.

Let us assume you have a class like:

```
@Getter @Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
}
```

Then you try to deserialize JSON like:

```
{
    "name": "Nomen est Omen",
    "agge": 1
}
```

As we know it fails because of misspelled `age`. To take more control what happens when deserializing you can implement your own deserializer, like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyClassDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyClass> {

    public MyClassDeserializer() {
        super((Class<?>) null);
    }

    @Override
    public MyClass deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        // Your logic goes here
        // I suppose here now - for brevity - that there will not be a problem with name
        String name = node.get("name").asText();
        // And that there might be with age which should not be null
        int age;
        String correct = "age";
        try {
            age = node.get("age").asInt();
            return new MyClass(name, age);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String wrong = magicalStringProximityMethod(correct, node);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Property '" + wrong + "' doesn't exist. Did you mean '" + correct + "'?");
        }
    }

    // This returns the closest match in nodes props dor the correct string.
    private String magicalStringProximityMethod(String correct, JsonNode node) {
        Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> iter = node.fields();
        // iterate fields find the closest match
        // Somehow it happems to 'agge' this time
        return "agge";
    }
}
```

There might be several ways to implement this depending on the actual need. This implementation approaches the problem so that it cares the possibly misspelled fields in JSON only if a POJO field can not be populated.