# Json wrong fields

Tags: java, json, validation, deserialization, json-schema-validator

How can I get all wrong fields names? For example, I have next input string as JSON format:

```
{
"name": "name#1",
"address": "address#1",
"pone": "000000000",
"ail": "mail@smth.ru"
}
```

Where 'pone' and 'ail' fields are wrong. It needs to use 'phone' and 'email'. I also use this property

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true);
```

For catching exception. And I catch it inside of try/catch when deserializing JSON to an object, but there is info about only one field in the exception message.

I need to get all wrong fields at once.

Maybe somebody have an idea about it? I also tried use jsonSchema but I think it isn't good idea, because in the end I have this message **$: string found, object expected** by this code:

```
JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(VersionFlag.V201909);
        InputStream stream=TestClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.json");
        JsonSchema schema=factory.getSchema(stream);
        JsonNode node =mapper.convertToJsonNode(MyObject.builder().build());
        Set<ValidationMessage> validationResult = schema.validate(node);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to spellcheck JSON object keys against existing Java object values using Jackson (or a similar library)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949503/is-there-a-way-to-spellcheck-json-object-keys-against-existing-java-object-value)

Comment: I think it's a variant, but I've tried and I had no result at all

Comment: TBH, I don't think you can do it exactly the way you want it unless you write your own validator.